# Return to same page of MVC 5 pagedlist (including filter) after a create, edit, details or delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, pagedlist

Using VS2013, MVC 5 and pagedlist 1.17.0.0, while on the index page, I can page through the data, add a filter, and continue to page through the data without problems. When I do a Create, Edit, Details, or Delete, it always drops my filter, and puts me back to the 1st record on the 1st page. How can I keep my current filter, as well as my place in my paged list?

Example, on a date sorted list of expenses, I've set a filter on year = 2003. I'm on page 4 of the list of 2003 expenses. I look at the details of one record, and when I return to the list, I'm back on the 1st page of 2014 expenses (sorted on date descending) - I've lost both the filter, and the page I was on (page 4 in 2003).

Sorry, new at this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently looking for a fully generalizable approach to this for complex filters, but here is what I'm using for simple filters (which looks like what you're doing now).

Add the value to the ViewBag of your details record, then pass it back to your index (your probably want to do this for your page value as well).

So your Index action method probably already looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page, string filter)
{
    ViewBag.Page = page;
    ViewBag.Filter = filter;

    var list = // App specific magic using the filter paramter to get your list of items

    return View(list.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 25);
}
```

In your Index view, you might have something like this to link to your details:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", Details", new {id = item.Id})
```

If you change that to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", Details", new {id = item.Id, page=ViewBag.Page, filter=ViewBag.Filter})
```

Then your Details action method

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0, int? page=null, string filter=null)
{
    MyDetails details = // App specific magic to get a ViewModel for your details page

    ViewBag.Page = page;
    ViewBag.Filter = filter;

    return View(details);
}
```

Finally, on your details page wherever you have links back to the list, add in the two additional parameters

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new { page = ViewBag.Page, filter = ViewBag.Filter })
```

Now you should keep your state as you pass through your details page.

Comment: When I try `,filter = filterVariable` it does not show up in the URL. Do you know why? Only sortOrder comes up in the URL.

Comment: Great! it helps me.

Answer (score 1):

The way I achieved it, following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), is as follows:

- Make sure your filters appear in your URL. For my filter form in my
  Index view I use the Html.BeginForm helper and specify GET as the
  PostMethod of the form.
- In my Create/Delete/Update actions I create a ViewBag containing the Referrer URL (Request.UrlReferrer). I use this ViewBag to create
  a link to the previous page with

  href="@ViewBag.ReturnURL"

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use session variables, then one doesn't have to artificially pass things around.